plecs simulation of output impedance of switched capacitor(SC) converters
I am trying to simulate how output impedance of several DC/DC switched capacitor converters(dickson, ladder, and series-parallel) changes as switching frequency increases.
I referred to several papers; and according to ch2 of this paper(1), Rfsl(output impedance at fast switching limit) Rssl(at slow switching limit) and Rout(total output impedance) can be calculated and approximated as: 
at 2 phase switching and when duty cycles of the phases equal to 0.5.
Next this is my dickson converter circuit schematic & simulation script(it seems I can't upload my .plecs or .m file, right?): 
my simulation script runs simulations on 10 switching frequencies from 10^3 Hz to 10^7 Hz.
According to the paper I attached above, the output impedance should be plotted like:
: decreasing in log scale at SSL, and constant at FSL.
But when I acquired the simulation results and plotted it with matlab, I acquired(purple is the simulation result; others are calculated plot based on formulas of the paper):
this is my matlab code:
and you can see that I used correct R(Ron) and C(capacitor) values as the simulation.
Does anyone know why there is a log-scale big difference between simulation and expected result? Similar difference also happened in ladder and series-parallel converter simulation.
Thank you in advance.
(Note: don't care about annotations in the simulation script)
